# If lat/long are features in a simple regression model, is the model going to account for the distance between data items?

Tags: regression, correlation, spatial, linear

That is closer items (geographically, according to lat/long) have correlated target variables.

Example: prices of houses in a neighborhood are correlated.

One way to handle this (continuing with the example) is to explicitly include as a feature the average price of nearby houses, but let's not do that and just use lat/long as two features.

I am guessing the answer is yes: the learner should notice the correlation when the lat/long values are both similar.

For purposes of this question let's assume linear regression with several dependent variables including lat/long. For learning, we minimize the RSS.

Comment: The correctness of the answer might depend on what the "learner" or the "model" is.  Obviously a traditional linear least squares solution will not compute or directly use distances, but differences in latitude and longitude will be imperfect proxies for distance nevertheless.  Please, then, clarify your question: what exactly is your "learner" and are you interested in distance *per se* or not?

Comment: If you just represent lat and long by a linear term each, then this will clearly not do what you are expecting. It would e.g. mean that if you drive from east to west, typical prices would linearly grow/decline.